# Django: Return matching and non-matching records

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement an `OUTER JOIN` functionality with existing Django features/commands.

I have this model:

```
class ClinicDoctor(models.Model):
    doctor = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='doctorsF') # single quotes (') because User table is defined down the code.
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic, related_name='clinicsF')
```

and

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    clinics = models.ManyToManyField(Clinic, through='ClinicDoctor', related_name='doctors')
```

I need to get list of all doctors along with their associated clinics. I am able to get the list if they have clinics associated with them. But I am not able to get those doctors who have no clinics linked to them.

I tried this:

```
doctorsQuerySet = ClinicDoctor.objects.filter(doctor__groups__name='Doctor').distinct()
```

It doesn't work as it does sort of `INNER JOIN`

This query will give me all the doctors. But I don't know who to proceed to fetch all doctors irrespective clinic associations.

```
doctorsQuerySet = User.objects.filter(groups__name='Doctor').order_by('full_name')
```

I have to show clinics along with doctors, if they have any. It seems to be functionality similar to `OUTER JOIN`. How do we do it in Django?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you define doctors as users assigned to the 'Doctor' group, the first query is right:

```
doctorsQuerySet = User.objects.filter(groups__name='Doctor').order_by('full_name')
```

By using a loop you can now get over each user and read the data related to the clinics.

```
for doctor in doctorsQuerySet:
    clinics = doctor.clinics.all()
```

Since this will cause additional queries on every iteration you should consider to use a prefetch in the query:

```
doctorsQuerySet = User.objects.filter(groups__name='Doctor').prefetch_related('clinics').order_by('full_name')
```

Hope this helps :)